# Arduino RS232 Shield with SD Card conflict

Tags: serial, sd-card, rs232

I have an Arduino Mega with a [Ethernet2 Shield](http://www.arduino.org/products/shields/arduino-ethernet-shield-2) + [RS232 Shield](https://www.embarcados.com.br/arduino-rs-232-rs-485-hardware/)

SD Card works well with Ethernet2 Shield, but it get a conflict when I add the RS232 Shield.

Both hardware use the same PIN:

```
#define RS232_DIR_PIN     4 // RS232 Shield
#define AMS_SS_SD         4 // Ethernet Shield

 pinMode(RS232_DIR_PIN, OUTPUT);             //Set RS232 direction pin as output
    digitalWrite(RS232_DIR_PIN, LOW);           //Set RS232 chip as receiver

    //Set SPI to Read SD Card
    pinMode(AMS_SS_HARDWARE, OUTPUT); 
    digitalWrite(AMS_SS_HARDWARE, HIGH);
```

I dont need both running at same time, but I dont know how to make only one work at a time.

Comment: You will need to physically modify one of these to use different pins.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, do you know wich pin I could use for them? for Arduino Mega

Comment: Probably any available I/O, it's more a mechanical issue of what you can access.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, it worked, just moved the RS232 Pin to 5 physically. Set this as an answer. thanks